# How to use `execCommand("insertorderedlist")`?

Tags: html, wysiwyg, contenteditable, execcommand

I see some wysiwyg editor uses `execCommand` to insert DOM to div, such as: `execCommand("insertorderedlist")`.

I tried to write a demo, but it can't run. The code is simple:

```
document.execCommand("insertorderedlist");
```

But when I click "Run JS" button, it doesn't insert anything. Do I miss anything ?

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/olalaf/1/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your demo fixed by me: http://jsbin.com/olalaf/2/edit

You need an element with [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute set to `true`. This attribute enables editing inside this element. All browsers support it, but in a very poor, buggy way.

Second part is executing `document.execCommand` in a proper way so the selection isn't lost. That's why I added my own button. I think that `Run with JS` doesn't work because it's in a different frame, so that the selection is lost before command is executed.

Comment: Thank you! I found it only work on FF, not work on chrome/safari, are you the same?

Comment: For me it works on Chrome and FF. Perhaps this version works better: http://jsbin.com/olalaf/4/edit - it prevents from moving focus to pressed button by listening on `mousedown`.

Comment: On chrome, if I click on "Run with JS" first, it will work well. My chrome is on OS X.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting selection in "Foo"? You have to put a caret there. Edit: I guess you do... Then I don't know - it works for me without problmes. Quoting myself: "All browsers support it, but in a very poor, buggy way"

Comment: `execCommand("insertorderedlist")` command inserts also font and span tags and some font styles. How can I prevent this? @Reinmar